# Question on Custom List Button

Tags: custom-button, button

I have an Opportunity object which has two record types Type A and Type B. If I go opportunity tab and create new opportunity, Type A and Type B record types will be visible.

Similarly, if go to Account and scroll down to opportunity object and click on a custom list button there. It should open the Type A record type page directly.

Will it be possible by just hardcoding the list button to open up only Type A record type page without going for customization?

Answer (score 0):

I a user has multiple record types available to them then the record type selection page will be presented.

If you want it to default to a specific record type then you will have to ensure those profiles only have one record type available for their profile. In this case though the user will not be able to ever change the record type to one they do not have access to.

A user can set that the default record type (defined by profile) be selected automatically when creating new records by going to

My Settings ->Display and layout ->Set default record types

This will allow the default record type to be selected skipping the record type selection screen while allowing them to change the record type later

Comment: Hi Eric, I understand that we can set the default recordtype. But my actual requirement is as follows:

Comment: You can override the new button to redirect and use URL hacks

Comment: I have a custom object and its tab available for me. There are three record types avaiable in it type 1 , type2 and master .I have access to all of them with default as master. Now this custom object is a related list on Account and Opportunity as well. When I go to account page, under custom object related list I maintain a custom list button which when clicked should open up only first record type i.e. type1. If I go to Opportunity page , under custom objct related list I maintain another custom list button which when clicked should open up the 2nd record type only i.e type2.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I tried creating separate custom list buttons and with the help of URL hacking. It worked.